# Python Flask distinct two generics routes

Tags: python, flask, routes

In python flask I have two routes with approximately the same behaviour to redirect on another service.

The first one is to redirect a generic request to another API.

```
@app.route('/factory/<path:url>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@cross_origin()
def request_factory(url: str):

    resp = manage_factory_message(request)
    return app.response_class(
         response=resp.content,
         mimetype=resp.headers['Content-Type'],
         status=resp.status_code
    )
```

And the second redirect also to another service but in charge of the documents.

```
@app.post('/factory/doc/<path:url>')
@cross_origin()
def upload_file_factory(url):

    resp = manage_factory_file_message(request)
    return app.response_class(
         response=resp.content,
         mimetype=resp.headers['Content-Type'],
         status=resp.status_code
    )
```

My problem is that the first route is always triggered but never the second as `/factory/doc` is include in `/factory/<path:url>`

Do you have an idea how to manage that ?

I can't set the `/doc` before the `/factory`.

I tried to redirect to the second route if the key `/doc` was found in the url of the first route but without success.

Comment: My second route is only a POST method to upload document. I tried to change the order and nothing change (even if I set .route on the both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that /factory/doc/ and /factory/ has a common prefix, so the shortest one wins. If you set routes which does not have this relation than both or more can work.

Comment: I solved my issue with the help of your answer. I have changed my path with `@app.post('/factory-floor/<path:url_before>/doc/<path:url_after>')` and after I recombine the url_before and url_after to build the new one. Thank you !